# Drools Fusion. Update @timestamp. Why can't I retrieve the correct value from timestamp field?

Tags: timestamp, drools, drools-fusion

I declared the event by .drl syntax:

```
declare Event
  @role(event)
  @timestamp(time)
time : long 
end
```

So I can get the "time" field that's set automatically.

In my java rule I want to retrieve "time":

```
when

  Event($tsmp:time)

then
  System.out.println($tsmp);

end
```

I always print "0", though I advance the pseudo clock

```
session.getClock().advanceTime(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

(if after the advance I try to retrieve the `currentTime` from the clock, it returns 10, but the print into rule always returns 0, as if the time stamp was not updated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use

```
@timestamp(time) // this class member contains the timestamp
```

in a declare, it informs the compiler that your field called time contains the time. It does *not* imply that the Engine should set the time - you'll have to do this prior to the insert. You may, of course, use the pseudo-clock to obtain a suitable time.

Only by omitting this from the declare you'll achieve the automatic setting of the timestamp in a field managed entirely by Drools.

Comment: Ok.so if I want automatically set the timestamp and I want retrieve it from rules i can't do it...right?

Comment: But if I want set manually the timestamp as a fileld  (see http://goo.gl/cQzNwx  ) I get a "NullPointerException"